# Trocar resultados de mapas utilizando leaflet e state_popup

Tags: r, leaflet

Tenho uma base de dados de consultas médicas por cidades. Utilizo a função leaflet e state_popup para apresentar os resultados em um mapa, conforme descrição abaixo:

```
pal <- colorBin("Blues",domain = DATA$QUANTITY_MEDICAL,bins = c(1, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000,100000,300000),na.color=NA) 

state_popup <- paste0("<strong>CITY: </strong>", 
                      DATA$CITY, 
                      "<br><strong> QUANTITY OF MEDICAL CONSULTATION: </strong>", 
                      DATA$QUANTITY_MEDICAL)

leaflet(data = DATA) %>%
    addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
    addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(QUANTITY_MEDICAL), 
                fillOpacity = 0.7, 
                color = "#BDBDC3", 
                weight = 1, 
                popup = state_popup) %>%
    addLegend("topright","bottomright", pal = pal, values = ~ DATA$QUANTITY_MEDICAL,
              title = " QUANTITY OF MEDICAL CONSULTATION ",
              opacity = 1)
```

Este script só mostra um resultado por vez (consultas médicas). Gostaria de incluir informações sobre outros procedimentos médicos que pretendo incluir, como por exemplo, exames ou internações. 
Quero, para cada procedimento (consulta médica, exames ou internação) incluir um botão que trocasse o resultado. Na minha base (DATA) já possuo as colunas que separam os procedimentos que citei. É possível incluir este botão para trocar os resultados no mapa?